# How do i get results from my html form on same page?

Tags: html, forms

I have a search box to request info from an API.

BUT when I use the search box I get directed to a new HTML page with the results. I want to display the results on the same page right under the search box.

this is what I have so far.

```html
<form
  method="get"
  id="Search"
  action="https://api.hackertarget.com/aslookup/?q="
  ONSUBMIT="submit(); return false;"
>
  <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="k7" value="#ffffff" />
  <input type="hidden" name="k8" value="#222222" />
  <input type="hidden" name="k9" value="#00278e" />
  <input type="hidden" name="kx" value="#20692b" />
  <input type="hidden" name="kj" value="#fafafa" />
  <input type="hidden" name="kt" value="p" />
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="INFO" aria-label="Search" />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If you want the results of a search on the same page without a refresh, you'll have to use AJAX to make the request, as opposed to a `<form>`.

Comment: i dont know how to use ajax. i dont know what to search the web for. however i have used php in the past and javascript. do you have an idea how to do this with those? or can you give me an example with ajax? @ObsidianAge

Comment: then you have to use AJAX. this is not possible with html. here a [tutorial-link](https://makitweb.com/how-to-handle-ajax-request-on-the-same-page-php/) @user10212870

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Can you help with with ajax. where do i start? do i have to create an ajax form?

Comment: AJAX = JavaScript and XmlHttpRequest to send request to PHP (or whatever code is on the server).  A web search will find you thousands of tutorials on this.  You must learn how to do it if you want to update a page in place

Comment: @DaveS  Can you give me an example or a specific topic to search im getting alot of info to read on   XmlHttpRequest. I just want to get the results from the api on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [**AJAX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) calls. I used [`jQuery.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method in this sample code. You could also use browser's [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API or [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) API.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#Search').on('submit', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = 'https://api.hackertarget.com/aslookup/';
    var data = $('#Search').serialize();

    $.ajax(url + '?' + data).then(function(data) {
      $('.output').text(data);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="get" id="Search">
  <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="k7" value="#ffffff" />
  <input type="hidden" name="k8" value="#222222" />
  <input type="hidden" name="k9" value="#00278e" />
  <input type="hidden" name="kx" value="#20692b" />
  <input type="hidden" name="kj" value="#fafafa" />
  <input type="hidden" name="kt" value="p" />
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="INFO" aria-label="Search" />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<pre class="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I started reading alot of info on XmlHttpRequest non of them on w3schools had anything like this. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="onsubmitForm(event)">
    <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="k7" value="#ffffff" />
    <input type="hidden" name="k8" value="#222222" />
    <input type="hidden" name="k9" value="#00278e" />
    <input type="hidden" name="kx" value="#20692b" />
    <input type="hidden" name="kj" value="#fafafa" />
    <input type="hidden" name="kt" value="p" />
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="INFO" aria-label="Search" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    function onsubmitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var url = "https://api.hackertarget.com/aslookup?q="+$("input[name='q']").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }


</script>
```